# Is scaffolding only used to create a CRUD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC is scaffolding only ever used to create a CRUD view based off an existing model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default, yes.](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview)

> You add scaffolding to your project when you want to quickly add code that interacts with data models. Using scaffolding can reduce the amount of time to develop **standard data operations** in your project.

**However:**

> Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (currently RC) provides the ability to **extend ASP.NET Scaffolding** to meet the requirements of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent it is customizable.

[Creating a Custom Scaffolder for Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx)
[How to customize the generated files from the New Scaffolded Item dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/26/how-to-customize-the-generated-files-from-the-new-scaffolded-item-dialog.aspx)